# Issues with knitting R markdown to word

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am having issues every time I try to knit my R Markdown data to word,
every time it asks me to update some packages but the packages fail to download-

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'default/America/Vancouver'
ERROR: dependency ‘xfun’ is not available for package ‘tinytex’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/tinytex’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tinytex’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'default/America/Vancouver'
ERROR: dependency ‘stringi’ is not available for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/stringr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringr’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'default/America/Vancouver'
ERROR: dependencies ‘stringr’, ‘xfun’ are not available for package ‘knitr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/knitr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'default/America/Vancouver'
ERROR: dependencies ‘knitr’, ‘tinytex’, ‘xfun’, ‘stringr’ are not available for package ‘rmarkdown’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rmarkdown’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/6x/4jl208cx6zjgl0j7bt12pxhw0000gp/T/RtmpmR05CL/downloaded_packages’
```

When i try to install the markdown package it says-

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What version of R do you have?

Comment: If you are a Windows user, you need to install [rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) first to build some R packages in your machine (i.e. install the packages from binary sources).